# Get the outer most parent id of the Div in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi in my case I have use the div in the following structure.

```
<div id="Parent1">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="mychildDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My working scenorio:

I know the id of the child div, from that how to get the parent id. For Expample in this, want to get the id `Parent1`. Is it possible get the outer most parent id?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.parents()` to get all the parents of the source element. And then you can get the target parent's id by using `.last()`. Please read more about [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Try,

```
$('#mychildDiv').parents('div').last().attr('id')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PwKMS/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a simple css selector, it gets you the first parent that has an id-attribute:

```
$('#mychildDiv').parents('[id]:eq(0)');
```

The outmost parent would be:

```
$('#mychildDiv').parents('[id]:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) functions:

```
var parentId = $('#mychildDiv').parents('div').last().prop('id');
```

Please note correct usage of [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), rather than [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)...

You also need to pass a selector to the `parents()` function, otherwise jQuery will return the `<body>` element:

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/pQc3d/45/)

Comment: Read the edited answer... And see the **working** jsFiddle demo. You forgot the selector inside the `parents()` function.

Comment: To know more about differences between .prop() and .attr() check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score -1):

Well, technically if you're looking for the **"most outer parent"** it will **always** be `body`, and it doesn't make sense to look for the **closest** parent with a `id` attribute.

Why not add some **better** and **self explanatory** markup like so.

```
<div data-outer-parent="true">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="myChildDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do

```
$('#myChildDiv').parents('[data-outer-parent="true"]:first')
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simple and can be handled via **css3** selectors

here is a code in one line :

```
alert($('#mychildDiv').parents('[id]:last').attr('id'));
```

:)